# $(this) is alerting previous selected values in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `$(this)` to get the current selected(clicked) element of a specific class .For the first time its coming fine i.e i am getting the selected element but as soon as i click on second time it is giving the alert of the old as well as new selection .I am not able to find out what is the issue..
Here is the code..

```
            $('.l-one').click(function () {

             var tableName = $(this).text();

             //Table Name Lable
             $("#lbl").text(tableName);

             //Panel
             $("#Perticulars").show();

             $('.my-new-three').click(function () {
                 var dishvalue = $(this).text(); //get the value of dish item and display in the table
                 //console.log(dishvalue); 
                 alert(tableName);
                 alert(dishvalue);
                 if (localStorage.getItem(tableName) != null) {
                     alert("b");
```

In the `alert(tableName);` i am getting alert of all the tables selected previously .Please help me to resolve this..
Thanks...

Comment: You are binding a click event handler inside a click event handler. You are always *adding* handlers, never removing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below code . only  click assign events  to each time when you click '.l-one'. so if you click '.l-one' 3 time  'click' event assign 3 time to '.my-new-three'.

[unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) function remove event from element and [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) function attach event to element. so here as per your code each time when you click '.l-one' unbind remove click event from  '.my-new-three' and bind function again assign  click event to '.my-new-three'.

```
  $('.my-new-three').unbind('click').bind('click',function () {});
```

other way is to use separate  click event methods.

```
 $('.l-one').on('click', function () { });

 $('.my-new-three').on('click',function () {})
```

Comment: An explanation would make your answer more helpful.

Comment: @RadheyPandey happy to help you .  it helps you . you can accept answer

Answer (score 0):

Use separate click handler instead of using click handler insider another one. Consider this code:

```
$('.l-one').click(function () {
//code
}

$('.my-new-three').on("click",function () {
   //code
}
```

Assuming If `.my-new-three` exists inside `.l-one` or `.my-new-three` creating dynamically then use this:

```
$('.l-one').on("click",".my-new-three",function () {
   //code
}
```